# JavaScript Modal is not working even after all the classes and id are correct

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, modal-dialog

I am creating a modal using HTML,CSS and js by watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27JtRAI3QO8&list=WL&index=12
The problem is when I click on "view more"(Trigger that opens a modal) the modal doesn't open
tutor has created a function which accepts "modalclick" parameter but he didn't place this parameter in html.
below is my Html

```js
const mviews = document.querySelector('.s_modal'),
  mbtns = document.querySelector('.s_button'),
  mcloses = document.querySelector('s_modal-close');

let modal = function(modalclick) {
  mviews[modalclick].classList.add('act-modal');
}

mbtns.forEach((mbtn, i) => {
  mbtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modal(i);
  });
});

mcloses.forEach((mclose) => {
  mclose.addEventListener('click', () => {
    mviews.forEach((mview) => {
      mview.classList.remove('act-modal');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.act-modal {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<section class="services section" id="services">
  <h2 class="section_title">Projects</h2>
  <span class="section_subtitle">Done With instutions</span>

  <div class="s_container container grid">
    <!--==================== SERVICES 1 ====================-->
    <div class="s_content">
      <div>
        <i class="uil uil-object-ungroup s_icon"></i>
        <h3 class="s_title">Object <br> detection</h3>
      </div>

      <span class="button button--flex button--small button--link s_button ">
                                View More
                                <i class="uil uil-arrow-circle-right button__icon"></i>
                            </span>

      <div class="s_modal">
        <div class="s_modal-c">
          <h4 class="s_modal-t">Object <br> detection</h4>
          <i class="uil uil-times s_modal-close"></i>

          <ul class="s_modal-ss grid">
            <li class="s_modal-s">
              <i class="uil uil-check-circle s_modal-i"></i>
              <p> Implemented an object detector which identifies the classes of the objects in an image</p>
            </li>
            <li class="s_modal-s">
              <a href="https://github.com/">
                <i class="uil uil-github-alt s_modal-i"></i>
                <p>access the project(Github)</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="s_modal-s">
              <a href="https://youtu.OS5s">
                <i class="uil uil-presentation-play s_modal-i"></i>
                <p>Presentation of project(Youtube)</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--==================== SERVICES 2 ====================-->
    <div class="s_content">
      <div>
        <i class="uil uil-palette s_icon"></i>
        <h3 class="s_title">Real time <br>color identification</h3>
      </div>

      <span class="button button--flex button--small button--link s_button">
                                View More
                                <i class="uil uil-arrow-circle-right button__icon"></i>
                            </span>

      <div class="s_modal">
        <div class="s_modal-c">
          <h4 class="s_modal-t">Real time <br>color identification</h4>
          <i class="uil uil-times s_modal-close"></i>

          <ul class="s_modal-ss grid">
            <li class="s_modal-s">
              <i class="uil uil-check-circle s_modal-i"></i>
              <p> Implemented an image color detector which identifies colors in an realtime video.</p>
            </li>
            <li class="s_modal-s">
              <a href="https://github.com/Git-ysc/Computer_vision.git">
                <i class="uil uil-github-alt s_modal-i"></i>
                <p>access the project(Github)</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="s_modal-s">
              <a href="https://youtu.be/zufhUPOfNE4">
                <i class="uil uil-presentation-play s_modal-i"></i>
                <p>Presentation of project(Youtube)</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--==================== SERVICES 3 ====================-->
    <div class="s_content">
      <div>
        <i class="uil uil-bill s_icon"></i>
        <h3 class="s_title">Payment Gateway<br>Integration</h3>
      </div>

      <span class="button button--flex button--small button--link s_button">
                                View More
                                <i class="uil uil-arrow-circle-right button__icon"></i>
                            </span>

      <div class="s_modal">
        <div class="s_modal-c">
          <h4 class="s_modal-t">Payment Gateway<br>Integration</h4>
          <i class="uil uil-times s_modal-close"></i>

          <ul class="s_modal-ss grid">
            <li class="s_modal-s">
              <i class="uil uil-check-circle s_modal-i"></i>
              <p> Created a simple website where payment gateway is integrated.</p>
            </li>
            <li class="s_modal-s">
              <a href="https://github.com/Git-ysc/WEB_DEVELOPMENT.git">
                <i class="uil uil-github-alt s_modal-i"></i>
                <p>access the project(Github)</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="s_modal-s">
              <a href="https://youtu.be/lsQ9iSLcDo8">
                <i class="uil uil-presentation-play s_modal-i"></i>
                <p>Presentation of project(Youtube)</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--==================== SERVICES 4 ====================-->
    <div class="s_content">
      <div>
        <i class="uil uil-transaction s_icon"></i>
        <h3 class="s_title">Basic banking <br>system</h3>
      </div>

      <span class="button button--flex button--small button--link s_button">
                                View More
                                <i class="uil uil-arrow-circle-right button__icon"></i>
                            </span>

      <div class="s_modal">
        <div class="s_modal-c">
          <h4 class="s_modal-t">Basic banking <br>system</h4>
          <i class="uil uil-times s_modal-close"></i>

          <ul class="s_modal-ss grid">
            <li class="s_modal-s">
              <i class="uil uil-check-circle s_modal-i"></i>
              <p> Creates a simple website which has a Transfers table that records all transcation.with a dummy customer database</p>
            </li>
            <li class="s_modal-s">
              <a href="https://github.com/Git-ysc/WEB_DEVELOPMENT.git">
                <i class="uil uil-github-alt s_modal-i"></i>
                <p>access the project(Github)</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="s_modal-s">
              <a href="https://youtu.be/thdD__gFnOQ">
                <i class="uil uil-presentation-play s_modal-i"></i>
                <p>Presentation of project(Youtube)</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

in this file there is modalclick parameter

```
let modal = function(modalclick){
    mviews[modalclick].classList.add('act-modal');
}
```

where should i use modalclick parameter in html

Comment: Change to querySelectorAll for your elements and for older EDGE, wrap in `[...document.querySelectorAll('selector')]`

Comment: But even better: DELEGATE from the container